# AddOrder issue on WHMCS API

Tags: php, yii2, whmcs

I'm adding a new order using WHMCS local API. Everything works fine except domainrenewals fields.

```
if(!empty($_POST['renewalids']))
    {   
        $postarray = array();
        $postarray['action'] = 'addorder';
        $postarray['clientid'] = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $postarray["paymentmethod"] = "paypal";

        foreach($_POST['renewalids'] as $key=>$id)
        {
            $priceselected = $_POST['renewalperiod'][$key];
            $price = explode('_',$priceselected);   
            $postarray["domainrenewals[".$id."]"] = $price[0]; #renew for 1 year
            /*$postarray["domainrenewals"][$id] = $price[0];*/                       
        }

        $orderDetails = WHMCSAPI::callApi($postarray);
```

its giving me error "No items added to cart so order cannot proceed".
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to take another look at the documentation for [addorder](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/addorder/), the way you are building the `$postarray["domainrenewals"]` value is incorrect.  Assigning `$postarray["domainrenewals"]` should look something like this:

```
$postarray["domainrenewals"]['example.com'] = 1; //renew example.com for 1 year
```

It looks like for some reason you are using an ID instead of the domain name, I don't think that will work.